# There are 40 available time slots for examinations. You need to schedule the A and B exams according to the following rules:

Tags: combinatorics

NOTE: This is homework so would appreciate if I could get some explanations instead of just straight answers.

Really struggling with this question and to be honest, don't really know where to even begin with it.

There are 40 available time slots for examinations. You need to schedule
the A and B exams according to the following rules:

• You must schedule exam A in one of the first 20 slots;

• You must schedule exam A and exam B in different slots;

• You cannot schedule exam A and exam B in adjacent slots.

In how many ways can you schedule the A and B exams?

Thank's in advance :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:

1. If exam A is in the first slot, what are the options for exam B?
2. If exam A is not in the first slot (for example A is in slot 2), what are the number of options for exam B?

Comment: 1. Well if exam A is in the first time slot, exam B could take up every slot after that apart from slot 2 which would be empty. 

2. If exam B is not in slots (2-20), it would just take up slots 22-40?

Comment: i made a typo earlier, I meant to say if A is not in the first slot in the second hint.

Comment: you are right that if A is in the first slot, B has 38 options.

Comment: I got 741 because B has 38 options, and by using by using n(n+1)/2. Does this sound right?

Comment: hmmm... 
1. if A is in the first slot, B has 38 options.
2. If A is in the second slot, B has 37 options.
3. If A is in the third slot, B has 37 options too.  
what about if A is in the fourth slot?

Comment: Yeah, then if A is in the first AND second slot, it would  leave B with 37 options? So 38+ 37 + 36 + 35.... = 38(38+1)/2 = 741. Doesn't this mean B has in total 741 options in total?

Comment: we get the same final answer. hmm... but you have an interesting approach. can A be in the first and second slot at the same time?

Comment: The rules state A and B cannot be in adjacent slots but nothing about A being in an adjacent slot with itself so I assume so?

Comment: Actually my working is just $38+37(19)$. 
Though I can't follow your thought, I verify that $(n-2)+(n-3)(n/2-1)=\sum_{i=1}^{n-2} i$. Hence we will always get the same solution.

Comment: So would 741 just be the answer for different ways to schedule  the B exams or would this by my answer for the entirety of the question?

Comment: The entire question. My approach is to enumerate all possible positions of $A$ and $B$ then sum them up, which is why $38+37+\ldots+37$, there are 19 copies of 37 in the sum.

Comment: Ahh okay! Thank you very much for the help.